# Do the parameters of a directive's link function rely on DI?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, angularjs, minify

In:

```
module.directive 'name', ->
  (scope, element, attr) ->
    # Whatever implemenation
```

Do the `scope`, `element` and `attrs` parameters of the link function rely on name-inferred Dependency-Injection? If yes, how can I make them minification proof ?

Or do they rely on good old arguments order for what's passed into them ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, the link function has a predefined set of parameters.

```
function link($scope, $element, attrs, ctrl) {
    //Your method
}
```

They are

1. Scope of the element
2. The element itself (jquery/mini jquery wrapped)
3. Attribute set of the element
4. Any controllers used in `required`

Comment: What about minification? `['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function($scope, $element, $attrs) {... }`

Comment: The link function does not require the minification array syntax.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the controller part? Is it an object with a value for each controller?

Comment: If I am seeing the following, what would the 5th parameter be?

`link: function($scope, $element, attrs, controller, e) {}`

Comment: It's transclude. function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {}     where it's a function that returns the contents when the directive has "transclude: true"

Comment: I think it is important to note that 4 (ctrl) will be the directives controller (and all properties defined on it `this.test = 42;`) if `required` is not present but a controller is.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to use DI with a directive (as I did), put the arguments to be injected in the directive factory function instead of the link function:

```
module.directive('name', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        ...
    };
});
```

To allow for minification, put the function argument in an array like you do for controllers:

```
module.directive('name', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        ...
    };
}]);
```

See the *current time* example in [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom).

Edit: [See here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oiVsKl09WJT1HqVLnUVU?p=preview) for a demo that injects the `$timeout` service. You can do the same thing when returning a directive (e.g. `return {restrict: 'E', link: function() {...}}`) object instead of a function.

Comment: Great quick and sharp advice! Thanks